# Add deploy name at headers on outbound requests

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, servicemesh, linkerd

I need to identify all requests of my applications, puting a header with their names, like deploy service-one put a header Referer=service-one, when is calling another application.
I want to do this on the infrastructure layer, because I have most than 100 applications and I don't want to change all those codes.
I use k8s with linkerd.

I can't use Istio.
It's a service to service communication, I can't use ingress too

I tried to do this using linkerd ServiceProfile and HTTPRoutes, but they just act in incoming requests not the outbounds